# Passing the argument name while calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which looks like this:

```
function helo(a,b){
    if(a)
    {
       //do something
    }
    if(b)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Now if I want to specify which parameter has to be passed while calling helo, how do I do it in javascript, i.e

If I want to send only parameter b, how do I call the function helo?

```
helo(parameterB);
```

Right now parameter a takes the value

Comment: That should work. However what I am looking for is if there is a way to specify the exact parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet would be to just pass an object containing all parameters:

```
function myFunction(parameters){
    if(parameters.a) {
        //do something
    }
    if(parameters.b) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
myFunction({b: someValue}); // Nah, I don't want to pass `a`, only `b`.
```

In case you want to be able to pass [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values as parameters, you're going have to change the `if`s a bit:

```
if(parameters && parameters.hasOwnProperty('a')){
    //do something
}
```

---

Another option would be to simply pass `null` (or any other [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value) for parameters you don't want to use:

```
helo(null, parameterB);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript parameters is matched according to order, so if you want to pass only second parameter, you must leave first one empty

```
helo(null,parameterB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing multiple distinct arguments, you can pass in a single argument, which is an object.

For Example:

```
function helo(args){
    if(args.a){ ... }
    if(args.b){ ... }
}

helo({b: 'value'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the below two syntax:

```
helo(null,parameterB);
```

or

```
helo(undefined,parameterB);
```