# pass a parameter to a function without an order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function like this:

```
let showNotification = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f);
}
```

While calling this function, I know I need to follow order, something like this (if I dont want to pass param for c,d,e):

```
showNotification(1,2,,,,6);
```

But this forces me to make sure I pass all parameter and it should be in order..

I am looking for a better way to pass param in this case.

I know that I can create an object of param instead where instead of passing the values. something like this:

```
let showNotification = function(objectParam){
console.log(objectParam.a, objectParam.b, objectParam.c, objectParam.d, objectParam.e, objectParam.f)
}
```

then call it:

```
showNotification({a: 1, b: 2, e:6});
```

I can pass whole object but this is not what I am looking. I do not want to create object every time for this.

Thinking loud, if there is a way to pass the string values, without taking care of the order.

I see some dead SO posts regarding this, but no one has solution.

Comment: create a new method with required parameters.

Comment: the thing is here all are optional, except the first param.

Comment: I can think of one funny way to do this, you can prepend or append(concat) tokens for respective parameter into your strings , e.g if you want to send parameter which represents parameter d , and string you want to pass is "myString",  then you can decide format of your token like $&d&$ , so your parameter will look like "myString$&d&$" , then in your function you can simply scan for token and assign it respective variable by trimming/slicing the token out giving you actual string value.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the response. I will wait for an hour more, and will accept the best answer (best way to do)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** I know you didn't want to use an object, but modern JavaScript engines are *really* fast at creating and disposing of objects, and with parameter defaults and parameter destructuring, I think an options object is your best option. See *"Notes on passing in an object (defaults, destructuring)"* below for details.

---

You've covered two of the main options (I'm going to make some notes on the passing-in-an-object version below). A third option is to adopt the a variant of builder pattern, but it involves using an object too. You've said you don't want to do that, but haven't said *why* not. Note that modern JavaScript engines create and dispose of objects *really, really fast* if that's your concern.

#### Marker strings

A fourth option occurred to me when reading [Bhushan Babar's append/prepend idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942573/pass-a-parameter-to-a-function-without-an-order/48944256#comment84892186_48942573): Instead of doing that, you could use marker strings in the arguments list to indicate what the next argument is, e.g.:

```
showNotification("the required parameter", "a", value_for_a, "c", value_for_c);
```

On first glance, that doesn't involve creating an object, but on modern JavaScript engines, processing it *will* create an object that isn't otherwise created: `arguments`, the pseudo-array of passed-in arguments. Because that (or a rest parameter, which also creates an object) is the only reasonable way you could consume such a thing.

#### Variant on Builder

In this approach, the main function returns a builder object with setters for the various options, and then a final "Yep, we're ready" call that starts the process (where in the builder pattern that final call usually builds the final object). Using it would look something like this:

```
showNotification("the required param")
    .withA(value_for_a)
    .withC(value_for_c)
    .go();
```

Implementing this is complicated relative to other approaches, but not *difficult*.

#### Notes on passing in an object (defaults, destructuring)

If you do use an object (despite not wanting to), you can use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make the object more convenient to work with:

```js
let showNotification = function({a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6} = {/*default if no object at all*/a: "foo"}){
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f);
};

showNotification();
showNotification({});
showNotification({a:42});
```

In a comment you've said:

> the thing is here all are optional, except the first param

That sounds like you probably want the first param and then an options object:

```
let showNotification = function(firstThing, {a = "default_a", b = "default_b"/*etc.*/} = {}) {
  console.log(firstThing, a, b);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`@T,J. Crowder` answer said better than this.  In other way, you can do this by using [spread Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). As  you said `the thing is here all are optional, except the first param`. So you should pass first parameter value. then you don't need to pass other value unless you want.But  you should mention the position of  parameter value as empty with `,` in an array. `In my case you should create an object or array.`

> **For example** . If you have a dynamic  array with  values(whatever but position should be mandatory )and position  `[1,,,3]`. then spread operator helps to merge that dynamic array with your function parameters.

```js
let showNotification = function(a,b,c,d,e,f){
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f);
};

let parts = [2,3,,,6];//Think it is a dynamic array on run time or compile time
showNotification(1,...parts);
```

---

And here the `@Felix Kling` answers could help by using [Named Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript)

```js
var parameterfy = (function() {
    var pattern = /function[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)/;

    return function(func) {
        // fails horribly for parameterless functions ;)
        var args = func.toString().match(pattern)[1].split(/,\s*/);

        return function() {
            var named_params = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            if (typeof named_params === 'object') {
                var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);
                if (params.length < args.length) {
                    for (var i = params.length, l = args.length; i < l; i++) {
                        params.push(named_params[args[i]]);
                    }
                    return func.apply(this, params);
                }
            }
            return func.apply(null, arguments);
        };
    };
}());

var foo = parameterfy(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log('a is ' + a, ' | b is ' + b, ' | c is ' + c);     
});

foo(1, 2, 3); // a is 1  | b is 2  | c is 3
foo(1, {b:2, c:3}); // a is 1  | b is 2  | c is 3
foo(1, {c:3}); // a is 1  | b is undefined  | c is 3
foo({a: 1, c:3}); // a is 1  | b is undefined  | c is 3
```

More examples:

[Pass a value to a specific parameter without caring about the position of the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868191/pass-a-value-to-a-specific-parameter-without-caring-about-the-position-of-the-pa)

[Passing the argument name while calling function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187438/passing-the-argument-name-while-calling-function-in-javascript)

[JavaScript: Get Argument Value and NAME of Passed Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009911/javascript-get-argument-value-and-name-of-passed-variable)

Comment: Please also note that spread isn't an operator (and can't be). It's just syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have attached some link for this same concepts. May be that links helps to OP what  he want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I hope the spread operator is working for dynamic data passing. If he have an array with dynamic value with `,,` a parameter positions. then spread would be merge that. Is am correct?

Comment: I get how spread helps here now (sorry for missing it), but can't say I think much of it; you still have the positional confusion. (Note that you don't have to use a variable: `showNotification(a, ...[2,3,,,6]);`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Absolutely.  That's what i have mentioned your name in my answer on top. My idea is not about hard coded array/object. I am answered for dynamic `array` with the `object` position.

Answer (score 1):

[Bhushan Babar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6655418/bhushan-babar) hasn't posted [his suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942573/pass-a-parameter-to-a-function-without-an-order/48942647#comment84892186_48942573) as a an answer, so I'll post it as a community wiki:

> You can prepend or append(concat) tokens for respective parameter into your strings , e.g if you want to send parameter which represents parameter d , and string you want to pass is "myString", then you can decide format of your token like $&d&$ , so your parameter will look like "myString$&d&$"

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder , I was not able to access this page, and all the notifications related to it were gone. Why did this happen? I was able to come back to this from my profile's 'all actions' tab

Comment: @BhushanBabar: I wouldn't know why you were having trouble with SO's website.